# Where can i find the system broken image icon file

Tags: macos, icons

I am looking for the broken image file that the system uses when images break.

I am on osx, but I don't really mind if i get the windows file instead.

I would like the file that the system uses - I am hoping it's vector based so I can make it bigger....

Thank you!

Comment: The answer will be completely different depending on the system, though.

Comment: i know. either answer will be useful to me...

Comment: Checkout Apache's icon directories, there's one in there.

Comment: Do you mean the generic file type icon, e.g. for PNG, that is shown instead of an image thumbnail preview when a file cannot be opened?

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, the answer is going to vary by system and browser.
Apache's sources include a `broken.gif`. Direct link to the file in version control:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/icons/broken.gif?view=co

Which looks like this:     [image: apache broken.gif]